# Laravel group the value by dividing the string from the database

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4. I have a big data table in which I have to group the data from string
eg.

> 131100580000 in this first number 13 is Unit Name, 11 is organization name, 0058 is machine name

and I have to  group the data as per **Unit Name, organization, machine** to draw the various graph.

I am confused how should I do it?

Comment: Share other example as well ? And your expected output?

Comment: Is this data stored inside in a column 131100580000
If so group by column name

Comment: their is only one table and 12 digit ID eg. 131100580000  has some value . And i am getting a huge list with value and these id . So this 12 digit ID contain various info eg. first 2 digit ,13 is Unit Name , 11 is organization name , 0058 is machine name  so i have to get data of indivisual units , organizations and machines.

Comment: @user2486
this is how my data is look like

array:9691 [▼
  0 => {#339 ▼
    +"ID": 10500000000
    +"DATE": "2016-03-06"
    +"Basis": "1378.92"
  }
  1 => {#341 ▼
    +"ID": 10500000000
    +"DATE": "2016-03-06"
    +"Basis": "-40.81"
      }
.....

Answer (score 0):

```
 $grouped = $data->groupBy(function($item,$key) {
    return substr($unit->theString,0,2);    
})->groupBy(function($item,$key) {
    return substr($unit->theString,2,4);    
})->groupBy(function($item,$key) {
    return substr($unit->theString,4,8);    
});
```

Comment: this is how my data is look like

array:9691 [▼
  0 => {#339 ▼
    +"ID": 10500000000
    +"DATE": "2016-03-06"
    +"Basis": "1378.92"
  }
  1 => {#341 ▼
    +"ID": 10500000000
    +"DATE": "2016-03-06"
    +"Basis": "-40.81"
      }
.....